# Apache can't access file while is has permission

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, aws, amazon

I don't want to allow others read access, so I have added my user and the `apache` user to a group called `apachme` and then set that group to all the files and folders I want `apache` to have access to, including the root of the webpage. I have then given group and owner all permissions. After this apache still can't access the files without setting the read permission to allow all(`rwxrwxr--(0774)`).

The folder that contains the index file, it's owned by `apache` with the group `apachme` and the permissions `rwxrwxr-x(0775)`

[image: 0770 permission on file]

with this I get a 500 error, changing it to `0774` will let it run fine

[image: tests]

These where just to confirm what user apache was running under and that it had been added to the group.

Comment: your apache run as user "apache" not as user "apachme", seams you make a type failure by assigning the group

Comment: Thanks @techraf for all the spelling/grammar corrections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the security point of view, it is not really a good idea to setup web pages with the same user of Apache. The Apache user should be able to read the web pages, but not write to them.

As such, in the standard configuration, it is normal for the web structures to be readable by all, and when there is a need to write, normally to be writable by the Apache user, which is a security nightmare.

One of the strategies to avoid that is installing/using mod_ruid2. https://github.com/mind04/mod-ruid2

As for Debian, it is enough to do:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-ruid2
```

Please do note the Apache default user varies with the distribution. In Debian, it is www-data, in RH/CentOS it is apache, and in SuSE, wwwrun. I will refer to it from now on as the Apache default user.

If you do not define any directives in a vhost, it will behave in the traditional way; otherwise the behaviour will be changed.

The idea of it is having a process running in the vhost with the user that has rights to the vhost, and as such, the files will have that ownership, and as you wish, other users won't be able to read them. Normally you define a user per vhost.

In the Virtualhost or Directory directives in a vhost, you define the user and group which will be active for that directory. The user:usergroup is what will be the effective permissions Apache will use when accessing the Virtual host/directory, and as such, any user that belongs to that group will be able to write/see the directories.

```
    <Directory "/vhostdir/">
            RMode config
            RUidGid user usergroup

    ....
```

As such, when writing the directories, now the files can be created as 660 with the ownership of  user:usergroup if they are managed by a group of users. Likewise, the files can also be created by another user with permissions to read for the world; however for writing, it won't be the Apache default user, but rather this other user.

The advantages of mod_ruid2 are then:

- in a virtual hosting housing environment, users can't read other users' files;
- in a single user, you can still create files as yet other user, and neither the Apache default user, nor the ruid2 user will be able to overwrite them
- more importantly, the written files will be now done with the ruid2 user, and not any more globally with the Apache default user.

From the github page:

> ABOUT mod_ruid2 is a suexec module for apache 2.0, 2.2 and 2.4, based
>   on mod_ruid and mod_suid2
>
> -it runs only on Linux because only the Linux kernel has implemented the required process capabilities.
>   -it has better performance than mod_suid2 because it doesn`t need to kill httpd children  after one request. it makes use of kernel
>   capabilites and after receiving a new request suids again.
>   -there are some security issues, for instance if attacker successfully exploits the httpd process,  he can set effective capabilities and
>   setuid to root. i recommend to use some security patch in kernel
>   (grsec),  or something..
>
> -there are two main operation modes: stat and config
>    1. config  is default, you must define uid and gid. If no [ug]id is defined the default user and group are used.
>
> 2. stat  httpd setuid and setgid to uid and gid of requested filename(script)/directory  this is good if you use mod_vhost_alias
>      for virtual hosting
>
> INSTALL
>    1. download and install latest libcap from here
>    2. run /apachedir/bin/apxs -a -i -l cap -c mod_ruid2.c
>    3. configure httpd.conf
>    4. restart apache
>
> CONFIGURE OPTIONS:  RMode config|stat (default is config)  RUidGid
>   user|#uid group|#gid - when RMode is config, set to this uid and gid
>
> RMinUidGid user|#uid group|#gid - when uid/gid is < than min uid/gid
>   set to default uid/gid  RDefaultUidGid user|#uid group|#gid
>
> RGroups group1 group2 - additional groups set via setgroups  @none -
>   clear all previous defined groups.
>
> RDocumentChrRoot - Set chroot directory and the document root inside
>
> EXAMPLE:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost example.com>    
> ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com    
> RDocumentChRoot /home /example.com/public_html    
> ServerName     example.com    
> ServerAlias    www.example.com    
> RMode          config     # unnecessary since config is the default    
> RUidGid        user1 group1    
> RGroups        apachetmp
>
> <Directory /home/example.com/public_html/dir>
>    RMode stat    </Directory>
>
> <Directory /home/example.com/public_html/dir/test>
>    RMode config
>    RUidGid user2 group2
>    RGroups groups1    </Directory>
>
> <Directory /home/example.com/public_html/dir/test/123>
>    RUidGid user3 group3    </Directory>
>
> <Location /yustadir>
>    RMode config
>    RUidGid user4 user4
>    RGroups groups4    </Location>
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a really good solution. Its even better than I was hoping for as I can separate the vhosts for even tighter security. Thanks a lot @RuiFRibeiro , this problem was really confusing me.

Comment: thank you @craigmosey Have a look at my answer (it is not the chosen answer) in this thread http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243490/editing-my-etc-hosts-deny to see how to protect Apache from excessive connections