# Give /var/www files access to www-data and my user?

Tags: permissions, users, webserver

Any folder than I want my php code to be able to save in or any file I want it to be able to modify has to be owned by www-data. This is annoying because everything I create or want to edit without sudo is owned by my user.

On the other hand, my school's server shows everything being owned by the user but issues like this never happen. www-data seems to have no trouble saving or modifying things despite not being owner.

How do I get my /var/www site working like this, where I can retain ownership of everything but not mess up www-data's access?

Comment: Have a look at my answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/262138/apache-cant-access-file-while-is-has-permission

Answer (score 3):

A solution which I usually go for on web servers is using ACLs. Basically, this means using additional sets of permissions, other than the usual user-group-other system. I find this particularly useful when I'm setting up restricted PHP access (for instance, using suPHP).

In order to maintain ownership on my files, I make sure they belong to me:

```
$ chown me:me /var/www -R
```

Then I give `www-data` read access everywhere (and access permission on directories ; finer settings might desirable sometimes).

```
$ setfacl -Rdm 'u:www-data:r-X' /var/www
$ setfacl -Rm 'u:www-data:r-X' /var/www
```

I also give write-access to Apache wherever I want it to write stuff. For instance:

```
$ setfacl -Rdm 'u:www-data:rwX' /var/www/uploads
$ setfacl -Rm 'u:www-data:rwX' /var/www/uploads
```

Note that, in order to use ACLs, you need to make sure you mounted the filesystem with the `acl` option. This is done in `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sdxy       /var            ext4    defaults,acl    0       2
```

(assuming `/var` is on a different partition, otherwise see `/`)

By the way on some systems, the `acl` option is set by default. [For instance](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs):

> As of Ubuntu 14.04 and for ext4, the above is not required as acl are already default.

You can check whether ACLs are enabled on a filesystem using `tune2fs` (assuming an ext* FS) :

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/sdxy | grep acl
Default mount options: acl ...
```

For more information on `setfacl`, [have a look here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that you could do (on a machine which you control) would be to

- add the group-id of `www-data` to your account's groups, and make the folders group-writable, e.g., `chmod 775`.
- Alternatively, you could change the `DocumentRoot` to point to a directory that you own, and have ensured that `www-data` can read (and execute scripts from).

Neither of these would be a satisfactory solution for a real server (it is not secure enough).

Comment: Indeed not secure enough, www-data exists for a reason, and giving it access to web files that do not need to be written is not a good policy.

Comment: Sure: but simpler than explaining how to setup user-directories on a web-server.  I've seen no usable information on that on this site.   The `setfacl` approach is a refinement over group-id, and will be harder for OP to use usefully.

Comment: I used to go with this approach as well, but things get tricky when new files get in the picture. You need to use `setgid` on the top-level directory (to maintain group ownership) and a custom umask which grants write-access to the group. Otherwise, you'll end up `chmod`-ing over and over again, not to mention that `www-data` might also create files (uploads, cache, logs). *As a example, I find Symfony development to be quite nerve-wracking in such a setup.*

Comment: OP's question was in a context where only the ability to update php-scripts was needed, not to modify logfiles.